# Multithreading problem on Sleeping Barber with Semaphores

Tags: c#, multithreading, operating-system

I found this code here online about the Sleeping Barber problem and there are two things I don't understand about it.

1) What's the "seatBelt" semaphore for.

2) Why the barber is going back to sleep even when there are still customers on the waiting room, even though the allDone boolean should still be false.

Thank you!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random Rand = new Random();
            const int MaxCustomers = 3;
            const int NumChairs = 3;
            Semaphore waitingRoom = new Semaphore(NumChairs, NumChairs);
            Semaphore barberChair = new Semaphore(1, 1);
            Semaphore barberSleepChair = new Semaphore(0, 1);
            Semaphore seatBelt = new Semaphore(0, 1);
            bool AllDone = false;



            void Barber()
            {
                while (!AllDone)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Barber asleep");
                    barberSleepChair.WaitOne();
                    if (waitingRoom.ToString() == "3")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Barber has to cut.");
                        Thread.Sleep(Rand.Next(1, 3) * 1000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Barber cutting.");
                        seatBelt.Release();
                        Console.WriteLine("Barber checks waiting room");  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Barber sleeping");
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
            void Customer(Object number)
            {
                int Number = (int)number;
                Console.WriteLine("Client {0} goes to the shop", Number);
                Thread.Sleep(Rand.Next(1, 5) * 1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Client {0} is in the shop.", Number);
                waitingRoom.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("Client {0} enteres waiting room", Number);
                barberChair.WaitOne();
                waitingRoom.Release();
                Console.WriteLine("Client wakes barber up", Number);
                barberSleepChair.Release();
                seatBelt.WaitOne();
                barberChair.Release();
                Console.WriteLine("Client {0} left the shop", Number);
            }
            Thread BarberThread = new Thread(Barber);
            BarberThread.Start();
            Thread[] Customers = new Thread[MaxCustomers];
            for (int i = 0; i < MaxCustomers; i++)
            {
                Customers[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Customer));
                Customers[i].Start(i);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < MaxCustomers; i++)
            {
                Customers[i].Join();
            }
            AllDone = true;
            barberSleepChair.Release();
            BarberThread.Join();
            Console.WriteLine("Fim do trabalho!");
        Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem), there is no `seatBelt`, so I will assume that the `seatBelt` here functions same with [other example](https://github.com/aseempatni/os/blob/master/5_semaphore/sleepBarber.c): seatBelt is used to make the customer to wait until the barber is done cutting his/her hair. So `seatBelt.Release()` means the haircut is done and the customer leaves the barberChair.

Without the original scenario description in the original post, I will try to judge by the code in OP posted:
in the Barber thread, the barber always falls asleep(`barberSleepChair.waitOne()`) by default,  until the very condition(`(waitingRoom.ToString() == "3")`) be met; but in the code sample, `(waitingRoom.ToString() == "3")` will never happen, because the value of `waitingRoom.ToString()` will be the class name of `waitingRoom`, which should be "System.Threading.Semaphore" and will never be the string value "3".

I believe there would be better answers if OP offers the link source of the descriptoin "`this code here online`...".